# how to make a dataset of handwritten arithmetic operators like MNIST dataset

Tags: mnist

I want to make dataset of handwritten numbers and arithmetic operators. Data available in internet is only about processing of the MNIST dataset. it will be better anybody can say even how the  MNIST data set is made.